# Showing both overlapping borders xaml WP8

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, border

I have two Canvas's which have the type Path in them. These elements are placed in a map, where I have an top coordinate and Left coordinate. These elements have different colors for their borders. At their borders they overlap, and therefore only one of the elements borders colored is shown. Is there an way to Adjust my xaml code such that both borders are shown, without changeing the top and left coordinates, because when I put these elements into my map I'm taking them from an list in my ViewModel. One example of two overlapping countrys would be:

[image: Example of ovelapping country]

So as you can see in the picture You can only see scotland and irelands borders, but nor Englands. The xaml code I'm using for each country is

```
    Canvas.Left="{Binding CountryView.X}" Canvas.Top="{Binding CountryView.Y}" Canvas.ZIndex="{Binding CountryView.Z}">     

<Canvas>
        <Path x:Name="CountryUser" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource StrokeUserControl}" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Fill="{StaticResource CountryBackground}" Stroke="{Binding CountryView.CountryColor}" Data="{Binding CountryView.MapData}"/>
    </Canvas>
```

Where CountryView is my list of countrys. I've looked into DashArray a bit, and is it possible to apply dashes at where the countrys share borders, such that at the borders you've got changing dashes of each color, but the rest of the country is one line with the countrys color?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to run into a lot of these little issues if you have the same experience I have in where they can become a big pain in the ***, but....luckily there's just about always a workaround or trick you can do that you'll pick up along the way. For your current issue you have some options to help your users out. Here's just a few of them;

`ScaleTransform` or `Margin` your `Path` you're using for the outline by 1 pixel or more to allow a little space for your borders to be shown next to each other and not necessarily overlapping.

Utilize `Opacity` between your paths whether it be by specifically setting the `Opacity` directly to the `Path` or by using the Alpha Channel of the color provided as your stroke, something like `#59ff0000` to allow for at least a contrast in color on overlapping borders. So say for example you have 2 Path's, one Blue, one Yellow, then where they overlap would show Green.

Create the contrast via `StrokeDashArray` as you pointed out by using the space / width's to stagger the border so even if they do overlap they still don't show over top one another, this is also a place where `StrokeDashOffset` could come in handy.

If you're allowing your users to interact with these shapes, I could also show you how to apply a `VisualStateManager` to the path and animate the `Stroke` dashes when they're selected etc to make it more visible to the user as to the area they have selected.

Anyhow, hope this helps. Let me know if you'd like specific examples. Cheers.

**UPDATE:**
You can use ScaleTransform like this;

```
<Canvas>
   <Path x:Name="CountryUser" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource StrokeUserControl}" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Fill="{StaticResource CountryBackground}" Stroke="{Binding CountryView.CountryColor}" Data="{Binding CountryView.MapData}">
     <Path.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform ScaleX="0.95" ScaleY="0.95"/>
     </Path.RenderTransform>
   </Path>
</Canvas>
```

You can adjust the Scale X/Y factors to suit your needs though .95 should probably provide a decent result itself.

Comment: I tried the Margin, but it doesn't work for me. So if you could give me an example would be nice. The opacity wouldn't look good, because some countries would be have four different colors for the borders.

Comment: What's it look like when you apply Margin directly to the Path? Does it not get invoked? If not you might try embedding it in a ViewBox and applying your Padding/Margin to it, not something I would suggest if you have a ton of elements though for performance reasons.

Comment: W When I try to apply Margin directly nothing happens, it doesn't get invoked, it is the same case for when I use the ViewBox. Any suggestions?

Comment: See my updated answer, you'll just have to go with `RenderTransform`

Comment: The idea behind it is good, the only problem is that I've got a lot of different countries using the same usercontrol and when I start rendertransforming to get the borders to fit, the different countries will need their own rendertransform to get it to fit.

Comment: Hey Chris, regarding the VisualStateManager, how does it work? I would like to do some indication that a user has selected / is interacting with an element. Will you kindly supply an example for this?

Comment: Actually, you can use the same Path or UC or ContentControl or whatever you like and just apply the Transform to it directly in its own space whether that be directly at the Path in the UC etc and it will just apply it to every instance by default. No need to apply it to each individual instance. As for the VisualStateManager route, no sweat, when I get some free time later I'll give an example unless you wanted to maybe ask it as a separate question, starting to get a bit cramped for space on this one.

Comment: I did try applying to the Usercontrol, which I use for all the paths, but because the data string in the Path is different each element will have different forms, and when I apply the rendertransform I get gaps in my map. I'll start a new Question for the VisualStateManager, I'll add the link here later.

Comment: If you're applying it to the path that's drawing the overlay of the map pieces it should just apply that small shrinkage in scale to whatever path is drawn? hmmm, maybe share more code, like is the map underneath the path's an image? Or are you drawing the whole countries that way also?